# Laravel view won't loop model even though it is populated

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm creating a web based interface for my dovecot database.

I can get a list of all the virtual domains in the database and the number of emails and aliases easily enough.

But when I try to load a page to list the emails under a specific domain, it goes weird.

Three simple models:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class VirtualDomain extends Model
{
    public function emails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\VirtualUser', 'domain_id');
    }

    public function aliases()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\VirtualAlias', 'domain_id');
    }
}

class VirtualUser extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];
}

class VirtualAlias extends Model
{
    //
}
```

My default controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\VirtualDomain;
use App\VirtualUser;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home', [
                'domains' => VirtualDomain::all(),
            ]);
    }



    public function domain($name)
    {
        $domain = VirtualDomain::where('name', $name)->first();

        return view('domain', [
                'domain' => $domain,
                'emails' => VirtualUser::where('domain_id', $domain->id),
            ]);
    }
}
```

and a couple of simple blades

home.blade.php

```
<p>
    {{ $domains->count() }} domains
</p>

<table class="table-summary">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>emails</th>
            <th>aliases</th>
            <th class="table-summary-options">options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach ($domains as $domain)
            <tr>
                <td><a title="view emails for this domain" href="domain/{{ $domain->name }}">{{ $domain->name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ $domain->emails->count() }}</td>
                <td>{{ $domain->aliases->count() }}</td>
                <td class="table-summary-options"><a class="ui-action" title="remove this domain" href=""><img src="/img/ui/remove.png" alt="remove"></a></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and domain.blade.php

```
<p>
    <a href="/">&lt;&lt;</a> - {{ $domain->name }} - {{ $emails->count() }} emails
</p>

<table class="table-summary">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>email</th>
            <th class="table-summary-options">options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach ($emails as $email)
            <tr>
                <td><a title="view aliases for this domain" href="email/{{ $email->email }}">{{ $email->email }}</a></td>
                <td class="table-summary-options"><a class="ui-action" title="remove this email" href=""><img src="/img/ui/remove.png" alt="remove"></a></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The view outputs the correct number of emails under the domain with `{{ $emails->count() }} - but the`@foreach ($emails as $email)` does not loop.

When I modify the blade to simple use the emails from the domain variable (`{{ $domain->emails->count() }}` and `@foreach ($domain->emails as $email)`), I get the right count and the list is populated correctly.

What's making it go wrong when using the emails variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a small change for it to work

```
 public function domain($name)
{
    $domain = VirtualDomain::where('name', $name)->first();

    return view('domain', [
            'domain' => $domain,
            'emails' => VirtualUser::where('domain_id', $domain->id)->get(),
        ]);
}
```

Without `->get()` you will get a query builder instance while with `get()` will return a collection. In the foreach loop a collection can be iterated while a query builder instance can't be.

Hope this helps